# "Tax on" vs. "tax over"

Tags: prepositions

Does one pay tax **on** income or pay tax **over** income?

I come across both regularly. **On** seems to be preferred usage, but I'd like to know which is most correct or formal and why.

Comment: I've never encountered _tax over_: can you give an example? If I google "tax over", apart from this question itself, every example on the first two pages of results is either _tax over (a period of time)_ or _pay tax over the phone_.

Comment: So you're basically saying this is wrong? Googling "pay tax over income" in quotation marks gives 24k results. Here's an excerpt from a result from the BBC: "Landlords urged to pay tax over income from renting".

Comment: @Robbert Google serves up different results for different people, but your claim that _“pay tax over income”_ in quotes yields 24k results seems **very** different from what I get when Googling the same phrase, which is only **nine results**, all of which clearly written by non-native speakers and dealing with Burma, Indonesia, Portugal, Vietnam, etc. (Note that the sentence following the one with the landlords is “Mi Chaung Kan land plight activist gets increasing jail term sentence”, which is hardly idiomatic English, either!)

Comment: @Robbert: The BBC usage you refer to is from ["BBC Burmese"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/bureve/all), which I note says about itself on that page: *Our coverage aims to reflect diverse opinions and offers in-depth analysis, making sense of the news events **to** the listeners. We broadcast **two times** a day*. Native speakers would almost always use ***for*** and ***twice*** there, so my guess is the text on that "subsite" is primarily produced by "not-quite-native" speakers.

Comment: Good call @FumbleFingers. Those are subtleties I too fail to recognise as a not-quite-native speaker. My comment below the accepted answer adds some context.

Comment: @Robbert: I'm no expert on the colonial history of Burma, but it seems at least *possible* the Dutch were influential. And/or maybe the syntax of native language(s) in Burma may influence learners to make certain specific "errors" (as we often see here on ELU in respect of usages peculiar to "Indian English"). Sometimes it's a fine line between "non-native speaker error" and "valid regional dialect".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not recognise "tax over income" and would not use it.

As you point out, a Google search gives some results for "tax over income". But:

- BNC (the British national corpus) has none (it has 10 for "tax on income");
- COCA (the Corpus of Contemporary American English) has none (it has 9 for "tax on income");
- Google ngrams on "tax on income, tax over income" says "Ngrams not found: tax over income"

This strongly suggests that native English speakers do not say "tax over income". And indeed, if you look at the first few hits for your Google search:

- the first two are your question
- The next is a podcast of the BBC's Burmese service
- The next is about Vietnam
- The next is a forum member with an apparently Dutch name, writing about Italy.

Is that enough evidence?

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, Colin. To add some context, I am Dutch. I suspected it to be a transliteration of the Dutch phrase "belasting over inkomen", but wasn't sure. I see it a lot in English articles by Dutch authors. It also explains the Google context.

Comment: I have often had the sense of being 'over-taxed', but happily it has never been over the amount of my income.